# cdata-section-elements not working for dynamically created element

Tags: xslt

I am trying to define some dynamically created elements as cdata sections, but it's not working for some reason:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" method="xml"
cdata-section-elements="DESCRIPTION2"
/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/RSS/ITEM/TEST">
    <DESCRIPTION2>

    <div class="container">

        <xsl:if test="NAME != ''">
            <div class="test">
                <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
            </div>
        </xsl:if>

     </div>   

    </DESCRIPTION2>    
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Test XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RSS>
   <ITEM>
      <CODE>41,000</CODE>
      <TEST>
          <NAME><p>HTML code</p></NAME>
      </TEST>
   </ITEM>
</RSS>
```

[Live test](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5i/2).

Sure I can add manually (`<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>`), but I would like to know why it's not working If I define it as cdata-section-elements.

Comment: Why do you think that you need to have CDATA in your generated output?

Comment: @MadsHansen In the actual XML there will be a HTML code, I just simplified the XML in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDATA serialization happens for text nodes inside of the nominated elements, if you put in elements there it doesn't happen. Note that, assuming an XSLT 3 processor with XPath 3.1 support, you can use the `serialize` function to serialize the content you build as html and then output it as a text node:

```
<xsl:template match="/RSS/ITEM/TEST">
    <xsl:variable name="html">
        <div class="container">

            <xsl:if test="NAME != ''">
                <div class="test">
                    <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
                </div>
            </xsl:if>

         </div>               
    </xsl:variable>
<DESCRIPTION2>
    <xsl:value-of select="serialize($html, map { 'method' : 'html' })"/>
</DESCRIPTION2>    
</xsl:template>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5i/1 then gives the result as a CDATA section

```
      <DESCRIPTION2><![CDATA[<div class="container">
   <div class="test">Peter</div>
</div>]]></DESCRIPTION2>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your content is well-formed XHTML, so it doesn't need to apply CDATA when serializing the content.

If you escaped the markup and constructed a string, it would serialize as CDATA:

```
<xsl:template match="/RSS/ITEM/TEST">
    <DESCRIPTION2>
        &lt;div class="container">  
            <xsl:if test="NAME != ''">
                &lt;div class="test">
                    <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
                &lt;/div>
            </xsl:if>
        &lt;/div>       
    </DESCRIPTION2>    
</xsl:template>
```

Produces:

```
  <DESCRIPTION2><![CDATA[
        <div class="container">  

                <div class="test">
                    Peter
                </div>

        </div>       
    ]]></DESCRIPTION2>
```

But why would you want to generate a string when you could have well-formed markup? It makes it a pain for everyone downstream.

Comment: Yes it works! But, what about this large blank spaces ? When you save this node to db you get something like this :____________<div class="container">____________________<div class="test">___________________________Peter ...